# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x00000000e7ffdefe

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

My Application is working fine if I open from home screen but when I open it from TestFlight application open button it crashes by giving the error that i obtained from Crashlytics.

```
    #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
    0  ABC                        0x4f1778 specialized AppDelegate.handleRemoteNotificationFromKilledState([NSObject : AnyObject])      -> () (AppDelegate.swift:183)
    1  Abc                        0x10f3b8 specialised static _VariantDictionaryStorage.maybeGetFromCocoaStorage(_CocoaDictionaryStorage, forKey : A) -> B? (ViewController.swift)
    2  ABC                        0x4f212c specialized AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
    3  abc                        0x4ed0dc @objc AppDelegate.application(UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool (AppDelegate.swift)
    4  UIKit                          0x24f82a6f -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 394
    5  UIKit                          0x251ac287 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 3086
    6  UIKit                          0x251b0241 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1588
    7  UIKit                          0x251c4811 __84-[UIApplication _handleApplicationActivationWithScene:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke3286 + 36
    8  UIKit                          0x251ad767 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 134
    9  FrontBoardServices             0x21ffbbf7 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 18
    10 FrontBoardServices             0x21ffbaa7 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 226
    11 FrontBoardServices             0x21ffbda5 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 44
    12 CoreFoundation                 0x208ef9e7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
    13 CoreFoundation                 0x208ef5d7 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 454
    14 CoreFoundation                 0x208ed93f __CFRunLoopRun + 806
    15 CoreFoundation                 0x2083c1c9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
    16 CoreFoundation                 0x2083bfbd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    17 UIKit                          0x24f7bf37 -[UIApplication _run] + 526
    18 UIKit                          0x24f76435 UIApplicationMain + 144
    19 abc                        0x4ef4ec main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
    20 libdispatch.dylib              0x204e8873 (Missing)
```

Any Thoughts on that why this happening.

Thanks in Advance!!

Update : - Code for AppDelegate.handleRemoteNotificationFromKilledState([NSObject : AnyObject])

```
func handleRemoteNotificationFromKilledState(userInfo:[NSObject : AnyObject]) {
  var pushDict = userInfo[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>
  let dict = pushDict["abc"] as? NSDictionary
  if (dict?.valueForKey("alert") as? NSString) != nil {
  let alert = dict?.valueForKey("alert") as! NSString
  if let type=pushDict["NT"] as? NSString {
     if type == "TO_ViewController_One" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_One"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Two" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Two"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Three" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Three"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Five" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Five"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Four" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Four"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Six" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Six"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Seven" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Seven"
     } else if type == "TO_ViewController_Eight" {
        let qcid = pushDict["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = "TO_ViewController_Eight"
     } else {
        let qcid = userInfo["abcID"] as? String
        self.notificationdictForkilled["qcid"] = qcid
        self.notificationdictForkilled["ToViewController"] = type as String
     }
     self.viewstate = "Killed"
  }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you calling the completion block after receiving notification (in the app delegate function `didReceiveRemoteNotification`?

Comment: There is no notification only thing is that when i open application from TestFlight Application the crash Occurs. See the updated Question with code.

Comment: There's 2 force casts in the first 4 lines. Is it possible that `userInfo[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]` is returning `nil`?

Comment: The Reported Error is in var pushDict = userInfo[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as! Dictionary<NSObject,AnyObject>